# SuperUser is not allowing me to post an answer

Tags: support

I can't post an answer to the question.
I get *Oops! Something Bad Happened!* page. There is the text from the webpage:

> We apologize for any inconvenience,
>   but an unexpected error occurred while
>   you were browsing our site.
>
> It's not you, it's us. This is our
>   fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error
>   has automatically been recorded and we
>   have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We
>   even try to fix some of them.
>
> It's not strictly necessary, but if
>   you'd like to give us additional
>   information about this error, do so at
>   our feedback site,
>   meta.stackoverflow.com.

What can I do?

Comment: Is it still not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me

Comment: I just posted an answer to a question

Answer (score 0):

We can't reproduce this -- and oddly enough I don't see any exceptions in the log for that time period, either.

Comment: So if my answer is correct, why don't you upvote it Jeff? :)